# Magento 1.9 - Newsletter email can't sent to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, newsletter

I was using magento 1.9, newsletter email can't sent to customer. I was tried many times in my newsletter queue. I have 200+ customer in my store. I need to sent offer products & Coupon codes via newsletter.

**Note: I didn't touch any core files & mail related files.**

Comment: Did you check the email template it's loading or not

Comment: update your error.log

Comment: yes, its loading, i can preview my desings

Comment: any error.log.....

Comment: no errors, its blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Try email client like zogo mail & email chimp. It may help us.